# Mac -> Eclipse -> Emulator (AVDM) -> doesn't load the VD?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-emulator

First post, and new developer.

I installed on my Mac (10.6.8) the complete package from [Google](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk) and proceeded to open the SDK Manager and downloading everything. I then installed the IntelHAXM_1.0.8.dmg and rebooted. I created a couple of virtual devices (VD) in the AVDM and attempted to start them. They are not set to use GPU acceleration and have the skin to the first option (Skin with dynamic hardware controls).

When I click 'Start', the progress bar in that windows shows me its starting. Upon reaching the end, the window with the progress simply disappear, and I'm back at the list of my Virtual Devices. I thought, maybe its an update I did. So I deleted and started from scratch with no SDK updates. Same results. Tried Different devices, with or without GPU.

The virtual android never shows up.

I also installed the Android Studio and the same thing happened. On the virtual Windows 7 I have setup on that Mac, the virtual devices load up fast. But on the mac itself, they never appear?

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not matter to be on mac or windows, it is related with android emulator configurations.

emulator takes a while, from 30 sec till few Minutes, so be patient.
if it did not work, try to use configurations like one of these to start up.

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: So, once I click Start, a window with a progress bar shows up, and once the progress bar goes to 100%, that window disappear. At that point, the AVDM remains, and I could click start again, the button is not disabled. You're meaning is that this behavior is normal, and I should wait? On the virtual pc I have on this mac, they load fast. On the mac without vm, they never show up. I am confused.

Comment: did you used the same emulator configurations?

Comment: I will check (its doing a windows update right now). I know on the windows vm I don't have the intel acceleration set. I never touched that. On the mac side I ran that intel app. Is there a log file somewhere to tell what happened?

Comment: Hi Samer, I did. It works fine in the Windows VM. It's something to do with the config on the mac. Starting fresh didn't help so its not an SDK update issue. Also tried the Android Studio, same results. I uninstalled the Intel HAXM and that also didn't do.

Comment: did you use Intel Atom or ARM as CPU/ABU ?

Comment: look, I faced this before,you install all packages so it is all related with AVD configuration like above screens, sometimes you have to change the device, sometimes it is about CPU/ABU I know it is a time consuming but there is no way to do it else trying to find the best tuning of it. one thing else about your ask if it is normal to wait, and yes it is normal to wait about 1 or 2 minutes to view the AVD starting with black screen then with android logo, however while this is happening you can monitor the PC RAM usage, if AVD is about to start it will reserved the RAM, else it will release it